# The meaning of 'brace'

Tags: word-meaning

> Clean shirt, he thought. He unbuttoned the top buttons of his trousers
>   and spread his knees, squatting slightly, to hold them up. Fool thing
>   to do, he reflected. Do it every time. (He tucked in the deep tails
>   and settled them; the tails of this shirt were particularly long, and
>   this always, for some reason, still made him feel particularly
>   masculine.) If I put on the shirt first, wouldn’t have to do that fool
>   squat. (He finished buttoning his fly.) Well (he **braced** his right
>   shoulder) there’s habit for you (he **braced** his left shoulder and
>   slightly squatted again, readjusting).

*A Death in the Family* by James Agee

Does '**brace**' here mean '**reinforce**' or '**freshen up**'? Or something totally different?

Comment: I can't find a definition for this *brace* used as a verb (though it can mean "swing arms about"), but I believe that this *brace* is used to mean "to wear braces", where *braces* (British English) means the same as *[suspenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspenders)* in American English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of *brace* here is probably *to put on a brace*, and a *brace* is one side of a pair of *braces* (British English) or *suspenders* (American English). So he is probably pulling the appropriate brace/suspender over his right shoulder and then then pulling the other one over his left shoulder. Braces these days are considered old-fashioned, old-school, but on the other hand, things usually go out of style and then come back in style.

See [Oxford 1.6](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/brace):

**braces** - British term for suspenders

The author is just using the article of clothing (*brace*) as a verb to mean *put on or attach the article of clothing*. It is akin to the sense of **to brace** = *To encompass, surround, gird, encircle; also, causally, to put round, make to surround* and *To clasp, fasten up tightly, gird: sometimes with a reference to one or other of the senses of brace*, etc (*Oxford English Dictionary*).

[image]

Advertising photo for braces, from [Black Lapel](https://blacklapel.com/thecompass/suspenders-braces-for-men-menswear-suspenders-for-men/). From a blog article: *Brace yourself: how to wear suspenders*.

[image]